# How can I embed a licence.licx file in a cpp executable?

Tags: c#, c++

We are using a third party UI component which requires a licence.licx file. The problem is that the executable is a cpp project and embedding the licence.licx file into the dll which actually uses the third party component does not seem to work. By "does not work" I mean that we get runtime licensing errors when executing the program on a machine which does not have the third party lib installed. We are also using Prism, which means that the dll's are dynamically loaded at runtime.

Does anyone know how I can embed the licence.licx file into the cpp project or get the licensing system to resolve the licence file from a different location?

Comment: Have you contacted the UI component vendor ? Perhaps they can provide some alternate way for the licensing system to work.

Comment: I took a dive into Reflector and found out that they had created their own license provider so I basically don't have to embed the .licx file in the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [Assembly Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) can add resources to any PE file, including the EXE generated by the native C++ compiler. You'd do this as a post-build step.